# Is there a way to cast the vaadin UI class to some class inheriting from it?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

My problem is that when I call `(SsoUI) UI.getCurrent()`, where `SsoUI` inherits from `UI`, I get a `ClassCastException` at runtime saying that `UI cannot be cast to SsoUI`.

Just to give some context, we implemented SSO between a suite of applications in Vaadin 7 using Hazelcast, and the Hazelcast instance reference is accessed through this class `SsoUI`. So at some point in our code there is this line:

```
HazelcastInstance hi = SsoUI.getCurrentSsoUI().getHazelcastInstance();
```

where

```
public static SsoUI getSsoUI() {
    return (SsoUI) UI.getCurrent();
}
```

and everything works fine.

So now we are developing new applications on vaadin 14 and I tried to replicate the same structure to handle single sign on, but now I get the error I wrote at the beginning, a ClassCastException.

Am I missing something or are there differences between UI in vaadin 7 and UI in vaadin 14 which render this approach unusable?

**Edit**: to clarify, SSO stands for Single Sign On and SsoUI is my custom class which extends UI.

Comment: What is “SSO”? Is `SsoUI` your own custom class?

Comment: SSO stands for Single Sign On and yes, SsoUI is my own custom class, I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: This should work, but apparently your own UI class is not present at the given moment...

Comment: But if it's like you say, shouldn't it throw a ClassNotFoundException rather than a ClassCastException?

Comment: Custom UI classes are discouraged and you are probably going to run in a lot of problems in the long run. See this comment of Leif https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10696#issuecomment-823226267

Comment: A ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the class is not found on the classpath. For instance when you try to load something via Class.forName(...).
In your case an instance of UI is found that is _not_ an instance of SsoUI.

Comment: How do you have configured the use of your own UI class? The error would indicate, that the UI instance is the default, hence the cast error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something or are there differences between UI in vaadin 7 and UI in vaadin 14 which render this approach unusable?

Yes, there is a difference. You're not expected to extend the `UI` class in Vaadin 10 or later.

To [quote Leif Åstrand](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10696#issuecomment-823226267) of Vaadin Ltd.:

> Using a custom UI class has been deprecated but still functioning since Vaadin 10. We would like to encourage application developers to move away from that pattern so that we could eventually simplify the internal implementation. …

## `ComponentUtil`

If you need to store some object so that it's accessible where the current `UI` object is available, you can use the [`ComponentUtil`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html) class to map values to the current [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) instance.

- To set a value:
  [`ComponentUtil.setData(UI.getCurrent(), \[key or class\], \[value\])`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html#setData(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component,java.lang.Class,T))
- To read a value:
  [`ComponentUtil.getData(UI.getCurrent(), \[key or class\])`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html#getData(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component,java.lang.Class))

Comment: I read about this approach in the github issue posted in the comments and I will try it, I need to do a bit of refactoring first though.